# Loading FMOD sound bank on Android and cocos2d-x

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, fmod

I have a game that is running on iOS and Win32 written using cocos2d-x c++.  I also use FMOD Studio for sound in the game.

I am now porting the game to Android, and I am having issues with FMOD on Android.  I assume the issue is related to asset loading.

Currently the sound system initializes successfully.  I use the following code to load banks, which works on iOS and Windows:

```
void FMODWrapper::loadBank(const char * bankFile)
{
    FMOD_RESULT result;
    std::string path = FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename(bankFile);

    FMOD::Studio::Bank *bank;
    if (path.size() > 0)
    {
        result = system->loadBankFile(path.c_str(), FMOD_STUDIO_LOAD_BANK_NORMAL, &bank);
        if (result != FMOD_OK)
        {
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)
                LOGD("FMOD error! Unable to load bank: %s %d\n", path.c_str(), result);
#else
                printf("FMOD error! Unable to load bank: %s\n", path.c_str());
#endif
        }
        _loadedBanks.push_back(bank);
    }
}
```

When I run this with the FMOD debug libs I get the following output:

> 11-02 20:48:50.173: I/fmod(2459): FMOD:
>   AsyncCommand_system_loadBankFile::executeMain : Failed to open file
>   'assets/Sound/MX_AND_SFX_MASTER_BANK.bank' 11-02 20:48:50.173:
>   I/fmod(2459): ../../src/fmod_asynccommand_impl.cpp(443) : FMOD error
>   (20) : File not found.  11-02 20:48:50.173: I/fmod(2459): FMOD:
>   Debug_OutputTrace              :
>   ../../src/fmod_asynccommand_impl.cpp(443) : FMOD error (20) : File not
>   found.

assets/Sound/MX_AND_SFX_MASTER_BANK.bank is correct as far as where my assets reside in my eclipse project.

Anyone have any insight on what I should be passing in to the loadBankFile() call.

Also, I tried using loadBankMemory with FileUtils::getDataFromFile().  This resulted in sound being played, but it was just noise. So not quite what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the assets are being written into the APK, to access those resource prefix your file path with file:///android_asset/

Answer (score 0):

file:///android_asset/ solved the problem for me with cocos2dx while trying to use an external library, fmod in this case.